# Problem in Element-wise right division in porting matlab project in python project

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to convert a matlab file to python.
in particular I would like to convert this instruction

```
  meanIntensity = conv2(Color_channels, ones(1, SamplingRate), 'same')./n;
```

where ./n is Element-wise right division by "n" variable.

So i convert in:

```
  meanIntensity = signal.convolve2d(Color_channels, np.ones((1, SamplingRate)), 'same')/n
```

but i have this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,1363) (3,4089)
```

How i can resolve it?

edit:

```
SamplingRate = 60 
n = signal.convolve2d(np.ones((3, dataLength)), np.ones((1, SamplingRate)), boundary='symm', mode='same')



Color_channels.shape = (3, 1363)
```

Comment: What is the dimension of Color_channels (with `Color_channels.shape`)? and what are the values of `SamplingRate`, and `n`?

Comment: SamplingRate = 60
 n =  signal.convolve2d(np.ones((3, dataLength)), np.ones((1, SamplingRate)), boundary='symm', mode='same')

Color_channels.shape = (3, 1363)

Comment: There is not nearly enough information in this post to help you. Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.